# How to make a <li> tag auto-resize

Tags: css

I have this li which has a height of 60px.

But if I put my content with has more than 200 letters, the content goes outside the li.

How to make li grow by itself?

```css
 #myUL li 
{
    height: 60px;
              
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>
   <span class="post">ljcbnvkdsjbvdskjbvdskjbvdskjvbsdkjbvksdjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbdskjvbdskjbvsdbvsdkjdbvdskjbvdksjvbsdkjbvsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkvjbsdkjvbdskjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkjvbsdkvjbsdvkjbsdkvjbsdvkjdsbv
   </span>
   <span class="close">&#215;</span>
   <div class="id-content">
   <span class="content">By </span>Mera Yahan
   <span class="content"> @ </span> 11:21 pm                
   </div>
 </li>
 <hr />
</ul>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has:

```
#myUL li 
{
  height: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

You should have:

```
#myUL li 
{
  min-height: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #myUL li 
{
    height:60px;
     overflow:auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-height: auto;
}
```

You can add overflow property to get a desired result.

or simply

```
#myUL li 
{
    height:auto;

    word-wrap: break-word;

}
```